# Dockerfile for Google Cloud Functions

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-functions, knative

I am reading [this GitOps-style](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/gitops-cloud-build) article on google cloud and I am now wondering how can I substitute the sample [python application](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/gitops-cloud-build#create_the_git_repositories_in) which they clone from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-gitops-tutorial-cloudbuild) with a Google Cloud Function (GCF) which is being triggered by Google Cloud Storage (GCS).

[This article](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/testing/test-background) describes how you can unit test, integration test and system test a GCF and I would like to apply this in the GitOps-style continuous delivery sample. But, for that purpose I would need a specific Dockerfile (I suppose) similar to this one (but related to node.js):

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
RUN pip install flask
WORKDIR /app
COPY app.py /app/app.py
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["/app/app.py"]
```

and maybe the **yaml** file. I would be happy if you could give me some directions. I am quite new to dockers, containers and kubernetes as a whole.

From what I understand, the syntax of the Dockerfile describes your project type and the runtime for it. So, in my case I guess I need to describe Google's runtime for executing cloud functions. I am no sure this is possible?

Comment: I'd suggest having a read at this article and see if it resolves some or all of the questions .... https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-functions

Comment: @Kolban this one describes the deployment process but it says nothing about running a cloud function in a docker container.

Comment: I cannot understand why you want to do it this way... Isn't cloud function intended to do not care about virtualization, containerization, servers etc.? Seems you want to do something that Google Cloud Functions want to avoid...

Comment: @WitoldSuryjak If you want, you can add it as an answer and I will accept it. You can attach this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPqN1pxF1lk

Comment: Yea, Thanks @user2128702, I was considering it as an answer, but I was afraid I misunderstood something....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot understand why you want to do it this way... Isn't cloud function intended to do not care about virtualization, containerization, servers etc.? Seems you want to do something that Google Cloud Functions want to avoid...

As requested I am attaching [this](http://youtube.com/watch?v=UPqN1pxF1lk) . It's really worth to watch.

Comment: And what happens when you need a dependency (like zbar) that is not installed by default in the runtime container? Some degree of customization is always needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case sounds like GCR (Google Cloud Run) is the solution you want, it runs docker containers.